# I don't understand why the route path and navigate path can be different and still work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I register a post, the code navigates using the following approach. It is functioning properly, but I don't understand why it works. Here's my code.

```
const WriteActionButtonsContainer = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { title, body, tags, post, postError } = useSelector(({ write }) => ({
    title: write.title,
    body: write.body,
    tags: write.tags,
    post: write.post,
    postError: write.postError,
  }));

  const onPublish = () => {
    dispatch(writePost({ title, body, tags }));
  };

  const onCancel = () => {
    navigate(-1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (post) {
      console.log("post: ", post);
      const { _id, user } = post;
      navigate(`/@${user.username}/${_id}`);
    }
    if (postError) {
      console.log(postError);
    }
  }, [navigate, post, postError]);


  return <WriteActionButtons onPublish={onPublish} onCancel={onCancel} />;
};

export default WriteActionButtonsContainer;
```

Here is the issue. route path and navigate path can be different? (Its working, but I can't understand.)

```
 navigate(`/@${user.username}/${_id}`);
```

```
<Route path="/:username">
        <Route index element={<PostList />} />
        <Route path=":postId" element={<Post />} />
      </Route>
```

When I include an "@" symbol in the route path, it doesn't render the screen. I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm cloning a project that uses React and Redux to create a blog, and in the original project, they include the "@" symbol. like this.  <Route path="/@:username">

This is code and image when I change the code with <Route path="/@:username">

```
 <Route path="/@:username">
        <Route index element={<PostList />} />
        <Route path=":postId" element={<Post />} />
      </Route>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFSQO.png)

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what exactly you are saying is, or isn't, working when you include the `"@"` character in the URL path. Can you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: The paths with `"@"` appear to work here in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/i-dont-understand-why-the-route-path-and-navigate-path-can-be-different-and-sti-t18zmo) demo.

Comment: Yes. It isn't working when I include the "@" character in the URL path with error message : No routes matched location.

But It seems to be working fine in the code sandbox. It could be an issue specific to my working environment. I can't figure out the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed different behaviors of the route matching within minor versions of `react-router@6`. For example, the `path="/@:username"` seems to work only in pre-v6.5 versions of RRD. From v6.5.0 and on I'm seeing the same code create a render loop. V6.5.0 is when the RRD maintainers reintroduced optional path segments, so it's possible they reworked the entire path matching logic to allow this, and "broke" any previously undocumented and unspecified behaviors.

As far as I understand `path="/@:username"` ***should not*** work in `react-router-dom@6` as it doesn't support partial [dynamic path segments](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments). Since RRDv6 doesn't officially support dynamic partial path segments it is best to stick to using complete path segments, e.g. `path="/:username"`, which would still match any path segment to the `username` path param, including those that start with the `"@"` character.

```
<Route path="/:username">
  <Route index element={<PostList />} />
  <Route path=":postId" element={<Post />} />
</Route>
```

If the `"@"` is included as part of the URL path but you want to omit it from any *actual* "username" value you want to reference then you can strip it off in the routed components.

For example:

Pattern: `path="/@:username"`
Path: `"/@drew-reese"`

```js
const { username } = useParams(); // "@drew-reese"

const name = username.startsWith("@") // "drew-reese"
  ? username.slice(1)
  : username;
```